# C3.js chart wired up with large number of items on the chart

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, c3.js

I am using c3.js, but the chart is getting wired up when I have lot many carriers in the chart. How can I dynamically increase the height of the chart based on the number of carriers? I tried to use size attribute but it is not working. Please find my wired up chart below, is there any fix for this?

I don't know the reason why the attached image is not appearing here.

In essence under columns in C3.js chart settings, I have nearly 100 carriers data. Then chart is shrinking up and practically chart is not visible only legends are appearing. How can I fix it?

```
columns : [
  [
    'carrier1',
    30,
    200,
    100,
    400,
    150,
    250
  ],
  [
    'carrier2',
    50,
    20,
    10,
    40,
    15,
    25
  ],
....
  [
    'carrier100',
    50,
    20,
    10,
    40,
    15,
    25
  ]
]
```

[image: c3Chart error with large number of check boxes]

Comment: you mind supplying the chart code? you've just given (some of) the data and the image....

Comment: Sure, but I noticed plunker is down/ or not running the scripts since yesterday. The soon it is up I will provide the sample plunker of the issue.

Comment: @Sean, I don't know the reason even though plunker is up, when I run scripts it is giving the error {  "statusCode": 404,  "error": "Not Found"}. Even some of my earlier working plunkers are also giving the same error. So I am waiting this plunker error to be resolved.

Comment: try jsfiddle in the meantime?

Comment: @Sean, you can find code in the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wiiUMk2KoHHrK4D1HdNu?p=preview. But still plunker is not running the scripts and still giving the error {"statusCode": 404, "error": "Not Found"}. So as per your suggestion, I tried js Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/madasuk/1agyz6yo/8/. But I am not that familiar in using Fiddle so I could not able to provide a running fiddle. For the plunker and this Fiddle code  the only difference is under colums: [], I have lot more data in my fiddle for columns : [].

Comment: By the way are you are also facing similar problem with plunker, do you have any pointers for me to make my plunker codes run? My work is really getting hampered with the errors ({"statusCode": 404, "error": "Not Found"}) I am getting for my earlier working scripts.